# Best practice of extending Laravel Base Model Class

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

We want to add get()Attribute methods for created_at and updated_at on each and every model in our application. So one way of course would be to write a new BaseModel Class and let all models extend that one instead of the default Model.

**Is there a (better) way to do this without using a new BaseModel class?**

The goal would be to make it impossible to create new models that don't use those methods.

Comment: The `Model` class is "Vendor Code", meaning that if you want to modify it directly, you _can_, **but if you ever update Laravel's version, the changes will be lost**. Creating a new `class BaseModel extends Model`, then basing your Models off this `class ExampleModel extends BaseModel`, is probably the best way to go about this. I'm not sure what "better" (that's an arbitrary word, could mean anything) would look like in this scenario. As long as you, the Developer, ensures that all new Models are extending your `BaseModel` class, all is well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, with "better" I meant some kind of best practice in case I didn't know about it. 
Editing the vendor ofc wasn't an option

Comment: No problem  And no, in my opinion, you have the right approach in mind. You _could_ maybe reinforce this practice with Model tests that ensure all Models are based off `BaseModel` and not `Model`, but that feels like overkill.

Comment: okay great! I think I´ll just try not to forget about it then, and overthink the test idea maybe ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command **php artisan stub:publish** to customise your default Models, Controllers, migrations, ...

After you run the command, Laravel will add a bunch of files in App/Stubs folder. Simply create a new customised method in the corresponding published stub file (model.stub).

Or read the description below for more details :

**Stub Customization**
The Artisan console's make commands are used to create a variety of classes, such as controllers, jobs, migrations, and tests. These classes are generated using "stub" files that are populated with values based on your input. However, you may want to make small changes to files generated by Artisan. To accomplish this, you may use the stub:publish command to publish the most common stubs to your application so that you can customize them:

source : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#stub-customization